# What's the difference between map and pluck in RxJS?

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to understand the difference between [map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) and [pluck](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/pluck) transformational operators in RxJS.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you read the docs? Try them out? What specific question do you still have?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @mgm87 said, you can perform an operation with `map`.
On the opposite, `pluck` is just taking a value.

For example, with map you could do something like that:

```
this.http.get('...some api url to get a user...')
  .map(response => response.json())
  .map(user => user.age > 18 ? 'major': 'minor')
  .do(isMajorOrMinor => console.log(isMajorOrMinor))
```

So you can manipulate your data down the chain even conditionally.

BUT, for me one of the big differences is that `map is typed`.
Which means if you have some data let say:

```
interface IUser {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  dogs: IDog[];
}
```

And you receive at some point a user, from which you want to get his dogs:

```
user$
  .map(user => user.dogs)
  .do(dogs => ...) // here, you do NOT need to precise (dogs: IDog[]) because Typescript will make a type inference
```

And that's why I'm always using map even to just "pluck" some data.

Answer (score 22):

The docs say

> Pluck : Like map, but meant only for picking one of the **nested
>   properties** of every emitted object.

Therefore, let's say you have

```
[{ name: 'Joe', age: 30, job: { title: 'Developer', language: 'JavaScript' },
{ name: 'Sarah', age: 35 }]
```

and you want a list of all job titles.

Using `map` would be kind of a pain (because of the nullability of `job`), but with 'pluck' you can write `pluck('job', 'title')` and it will traverse the tree looking for `job.title` - and won't fail if `job` is null.

Example taken from : https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/pluck.html

https://jsfiddle.net/btroncone/n592m597/

Comment: I only get 'undefined' printed to the console in your example?

Comment: this is an array of people, so you'd have to do `data[0].pluck('job', 'title')` where `data` has been assigned to the JSON

Answer (score 17):

**Stop using pluck!**

`Pluck` is now planned to be removed in RxJS v8.
Do you know what is the reason?

Because after the addition of the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) in JS, it's essentially, just a weak version of `Map`.

So what's the difference between the two?
Both are used to "transform" the data that is going to be emitted.
`Map` can be used to... **map** an observable emission (like we do in JS with `Array.prototype.map`), while `Pluck` is used to **select**/**pick** a property to emit (without having to emit properties that we don't care for, hence improving the performance).

But even before the optional chaining operator, you could just map the properties instead of plucking them. The result & performance were/are about the same.

```
pluck('prop')
```

is just a shorthand for:

```
map(x => x.prop)
```

Well, then what was the reason behind the implementation of `Pluck`?

It was basically implemented to achieve **path traversal safety**, meaning you could try to pluck a nested property without getting the error (that Map would throw) if the property is not defined:

```
pluck('foo', 'bar', 'baz'); // no error if foo is not defined
map(x => x.foo.bar.baz) // error if foo is not defined
```

With optional chaining, this advantage doesn't exists anymore, since we can just do this:

```
map(x => x?.foo?.bar?.baz)
```

This is the main reason why the `Pluck` operator is going to be deprecated and removed in the future.
Another important reason is TS typing for pluck is quite complex and not as robust as the map operator.

Got that info in [GitHub](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/5453):
The commit of `Pluck` deprecation is almost one year old but I still don't see any warning of future deprecation in the docs, hence I am posting here since I think it's a good thing to know. I already stopped plucking for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

Map can perform an operation on each emitted value.
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html

```
// value from observable = 10
map(x => 10*x)
// value from map = 100
```

Pluck simply picks one of the nested properties of each emitted value.
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-pluck
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/pluck.html

```
// value from observable = {p = 10, w = 100}
pluck('p')
// value from pluck = 10
```

Answer (score -4):

They are very similar, but as I understand it, map works with an array whereas pluck takes the values from an object.

[This is the place to go for specifics.](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-pluck)

Comment: You are thinking of Array.map, not Observable.map. Also https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/248731